# How do I get the most recent report data?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to build a tool that collects a few data points from a user usage report with

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/{user}/all/dates/{yyyy-mm-dd}
```

Since the data is delayed - how do I get the most recent report? If I were to query today's (2013-11-22) date I would get something like:

```
Data for dates later than 2013-11-19 is not yet available. Please check back later
```

Is there a set number of days/hours for reports to be available - or do I have to trial and error backwards until I get a successful response?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a delay of about 48 hours for the reports as of right now. However, if Google is able to improve on that, you'll want your app to be able to take advantage of those improvements without any changes needed.

I suggest you make a first attempt using *today's* date. When that fails, parse the error response to grab the last date report data is available for and use that value. This way you're always making only 2 max attempts and if Google improves the delay to 24 hours or even less, your app is able to take immediate advantage of that change.